# Translate \typeout to LaTeX3

Tags: expl3, latex3, write

The command `\typeout{argument}` expands its argument and writes the result to the log and the terminal. Writing `l3build` tests, I sought for an equivalent command in LaTeX3, but only found `\iow_log:x` and `\iow_term:x` which it essentially is a combination of.

How does `\typeout` translate to LaTeX3?

Comment: The accepted answer is correct, but I've always found `\msg_term:n` and the `\*_show:N` family of functions to be more useful in practice.

Comment: @SeanAllred I already knew of the `\msg_` family of commands, but actually wanted something without that much decoration. Thanks for the note though, as other people stumbling onto this question may need exactly that.

Comment: @SeanAllred The question was about `\typeout`, which in an `expl3` context is 'lower level' :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In cases where the 'built-in' `x`-type expansion of primitives is useful, such as `\(pdf)strcmp`, the team provide `\<name>_x:n` wrappers. That applies if the underlying primitive is expandable. In the case of `\typeout`, there is no expandable implementation and so this is not necessary. For these cases, a normal `x`-type variant of an `n`-type function is set up. In this case, `\iow_term:x` *is* the correct choice: this writes to the terminal and to the log and does `x`-type expansion. (Anything in the terminal output is in the log, but the converse is not true.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\def\foo{bar}
\typeout{\foo}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\iow_term:x { \foo }
\stop
```

Note that `\typeout` works with the LaTeX2e robust mechanism (setting the behaviour of `\protect`) which a LaTeX3 `x`-type expansion does not do. Thus if you are dealing with mixed material and it might contain robust commands you should use `\typeout`.

Comment: Not everything in the terminal output is also in the log. The important exception is the output of `\write18`. The log only contains, if the command was executed. The output of the command is in the terminal only.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek OK, fair enough but that's outside of the control of `\write-1` ;-)